# aws javascript sdk function to modify existing tags on a file in s3

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tagging

is there any way of adding a tag to existing TagSet to a file in s3 bucket using javascript SDK? This method:

```
putObjectTagging(params = {}, callback) ⇒ AWS.Request
```

overwrites existing ones and sets new TagSet. Is there any better way than getting current TagSet, adding a new tag to the array and pushing them all together once again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no way for now to just add a new tag to the existing set of tags. see [this bug report](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/486) which talks about this being a S3 API Issue and even [the S3 Rest API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketOps.html) doesnt seem to support the patch operation of the tags.

So you are left with first fetching the [existing tag set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getBucketTagging-property)  adding your tags to it. And then setting the complete tag set [back on the S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putBucketTagging-property).